# Inform a node that another node is closed

Tags: ros, shutdown, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am currently working on a roscpp project and I met a problem: I have a publisher node A and a subscriber node B. Now I want to close the node A via the terminal, and I want to inform B that its publisher got closed. Is there any possibility to realize this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67285/inform-a-node-that-another-node-is-closed/) by [RickROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/5414/rickros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never used it myself, but it sounds like [Bond](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=&name=bond) might be something to look into.

---

Originally posted by [stantol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2884/stantol/) with karma: 146 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5